# Several node server processes serving requests to several sites

Tags: node.js

I read many posts and tutorials on nodejs serving several sites on a same server: you launch 1 node process per site, and have ngnix distribute traffic depending on which domain the request came in with.

What i'm investigating is another way of achieving the same result:

Have a fixed amount of nodejs processes on the server (let's say 4 - 1 per core), serve requests from an undefined amount of web sites (let's say 10). So each node process would NOT be tied to specific domain:

> Requests comes in for domain1, ngnix would forward request to any of
>   the first available node process.
>
> Requests comes in for domain2, ngnix would forward request to any of
>   the first available node process.

In this way, I could keep adding domains/sites to the server, and have the 4 node process jungle to take care of them in an undiscriminatory way.

Is this kind of setup possible ? If yes, how should I organize it ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are looking to scale your application in multiple instances. Let' s assume that you want to create a cluster of 4 machines and let' s name them:

1. m1.your-domain.com
2. m2.your-domain.com
3. m3.your-domain.com
4. m4.your-domain.com

Let's assume that they are instances with 4 cores so it is a good practice to start 4 processes of your application on every instance and let's assume that your application will run on port 3000.

On every instance, you can configure nginx on port 80 that will forward the traffic to the processes within the instance. Then you need to orchestrate these 4 instances and you can do it with a load balancer. You can create one by having one more machine that listens to this domain lb.your-domain.com. You can create a load balancer by using nginx or you can use another service like the [aws elb](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). The load balancer now will be configured to forward the traffic to your instances by using an algorithm like the Round Robin. By the way, your load balancer will be open to the public, no one should be able to access your instance domain but only specific ips.